# Laravel Invalid MailChimp API key supplied

Tags: laravel, mailchimp

Laravel project showing nvalid MailChimp API key supplied when deployed on server but not on local server. The following is my .ENV file. I put stars just to hide the numbers. I double checked with my MailChimp credentials and all the details below matches.

**.ENV**

```
MAILCHIMP_APIKEY=********
MAILCHIMP_REGISTERED_USERS_LIST_ID=********
MAILCHIMP_SUBSCRIBERS_LIST_ID=********
```

Comment: this .env file is for a local server or live? either case show both

Comment: @JunaidAhmad this .env is for both

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the **MAILCHIMP** .env variables with **double quotes** as `"VALUE"`

And if Mailchimp creates their keys depending on your url, you could always double check if the production url is supplied in your Mailchimp settings.

Comment: I'm thinking the same. Maybe it has to do something  with the URL.

Comment: That's a good one, sometimes API's use sandbox and production urls!